# How to output the default 404 page within HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-404, authorize-attribute

I have written a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` having an override of `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`. This override conditionally sets the response status code to 404 with:

```
var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.StatusCode = 404;
response.ContentType = null;
response.End();
```

The problem is that the full response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 24 Jan 2011 16:43:08 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: private
Connection: Close
```

when I would like to send back the default 404 page. Something like:

---

[image: Screenshot of the default ASP.NET 404 page]

---

How do I do that?

Comment: FYI - When overriding HandleUnauthorizedRequest, you really should set filterContext.Result = {something}.  Response.End() isn't actually guaranteed to stop the request in the MVC pipeline, and you may find that your action method actually executes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is setting the [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizationcontext.result.aspx) property of the filter context like this:

```
var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.StatusCode = 404;
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
viewData["Id"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotFound", ViewData = viewData };
return;
```

where "NotFound" is an action of the controller containing a different action that was marked with my custom `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:
Create a custom 404 handler in Web.config as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="My404ErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Now all 404 errors go to My404ErrorPage.aspx (or whatever you choose to name
    your error page) and you can also redirect to it at will.

Maybe `"Response.WriteError(404);`

Comment: Unfortunately adding `<customErrors...` did not work. Also, I don't see a `WriteError` method of `Response`. Is it an extension method?